# VS Code adds text to closing tag when I paste it into opening tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code 1.14.1, whenever I paste something into an HTML tag immediately after the tag name, it also pastes the same text into the closing tag:

[image]

This doesn't happen if I type the text manually. I've never had this problem before; is it a new "feature"? How do I turn it off?

Comment: is it not that you have the cursor clicked on both tags?

Comment: No, I only clicked in one of them, and I reproduced it on multiple different tags so I doubt I somehow accidentally did that multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the mirror cursor functionality.  You can disable it by searching for this in your settings and uncheck it:

> Mirror cursor on matching tag

It is enabled by default now but with v1.42 will be off by default.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#html-mirror-cursor-off-by-default

---

v1.44 is making some major changes in how the "mirror cursor" functionality works.  It is now called **Synced Regions** .  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#synced-regions

If you paste something into one tag it will not also be pasted into the other tag if there is a space in the text you are pasting.

Comment: Ah, so it is indeed a bug in a new feature. Just found the issue for it here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87067